# laravel serve a page using http instead of https

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a filter like this

```
if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
```

this filter makes every route of my site to be served over https, which is good, except for one case. I have a route, which serves content from third party servers (which can be embedded ). These embeddable contents are all http.

I would like to serve just this route using http instead of https. Is there a way , I can do this using laravel.

thanks

Comment: To, all the editors, please don't disapprove the change. the change must be done. as because page is not the correct terminology while route is. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Request::url()`

```
if(( ! Request::secure()) && (Request::url() !== '/your/single/page'))
{
    return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
}
```

Comment: I am sorry - I hadn't penned down my question in an appropriate manner . I have done that now. Instead of a page (which i had stated earlier) I am wondering if i can use Http just for this one route instead of the whole website. once again, i apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a route to be handled differently, you can use a route definition like this:

```
Route::group(["before" => "test"], function()
{
     Route::get('path/to/route', array('as' => 'routeName', 'uses' => 'routeController@doSomething'));
});
```

And then in your `filters.php` file you can add:

```
Route::filter('test', function()
{
    if( Route::currentRouteName() == 'routeName')
    {
        return Redirect::to('http://example.com');
    }
});
```

More info on named routes can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: did that as well .. but in my filters.php Route::currentRouteName is null. hence i think that if loop would not be honoured!

Comment: yeah .. what i was thinking turned out to be true. I eventually ended up trying what was specified but it did not work.

Comment: My apologies, you have to embed the route in a filter first. I've updated my answer and did a quick successful test here.

Comment: Nope does not work for me. I am now getting a method not found exception while the protocol is still https

Comment: Ok, it was working on my side but I may have a different setup. I've edited my answer once more to focus on the one route you want to redirect. But this is actually a complicated way to just fetch some external content. You may want to use just the URL in your code using `url('http://example.com/bar')`.